# Merge multiple columns in one single column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm having a hard time solving this, i hope someone can help me out with some tips or advice.

I have a Table in SQL with 3 columns:

```
Pencil Sales    Notebook Sales  Pen Sales
     1                2             3
     9                5             6
     7                8             9
```

I made a query using "Union all" with the sum of each column.

My query looks like this:

```
select sum(pencilsales) from table1 union all
select sum(notebooksales) from table1 union all
select sum(pensales) from table1
```

and it gives me the following:

```
(No Column Name)
       17           
       15     
       18
```

But i wanna know if there's a way of sorting this new query by using "desc" or something like that and to add a new column saying which one is each row, like this:

```
      Sales        Name
       18       Pen Sales     
       17       Pencil Sales
       15       Notebook Sales
```

Hope you can help me out with ideas and thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from
(
select 'Pencil Sales' as Name, sum(pencilsales) as sales from table1 
union all
select 'Notebook Sales', sum(notebooksales) from table1 
union all
select 'Pen Sales', sum(pensales) from table1
) t order by sales desc
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked wonders i just have a question about this part of the query:  " ) t order by sales desc " what does the "t" stands for or what is it used for thanks

Comment: `t` is an alias for the derived table here. You could name it as you wish.

Comment: Im really new to stackoverflow and i dont know how to upvote you or close the thread to say this is solved, but thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good candidate for UNPIVOT

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Sales) Sales,
    [Name] 
FROM Table1
UNPIVOT (
    Sales
    FOR [Name] IN ([pencilsales], [notebooksales], [pensales]) 
) up
GROUP BY [Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't unpivot in MySql. The sub-query gets what you want.

Answer (score 0):

UNION is often not used in this case. SQL Server has the handy [PIVOT/UNPIVOT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to do this.

Also, your question is easier to understand if you have a key like "Sales Associate".

```
CREATE TABLE Sales
(
   [Sales Assoicate Id] varchar(10),
   [Pencil Sales] int,
   [Notebook Sales] int,
   [Pen Sales] int
);

INSERT INTO Sales ([Sales Associate Id],[Pencil Sales],[Notebook Sales],[Pen Sales]) VALUES ('Morgan',1,2,3);
INSERT INTO Sales ([Sales Associate Id],[Pencil Sales],[Notebook Sales],[Pen Sales]) VALUES ('Jane',9,5,6);
INSERT INTO Sales ([Sales Associate Id],[Pencil Sales],[Notebook Sales],[Pen Sales]) VALUES ('Jeff',7,8,9);
```

Looks like:

```
Sales Associate Id   Pencil Sales    Notebook Sales  Pen Sales
   Morgan                 1                2             3
   Jane                   9                5             6
   Jeff                   7                8             9
```

To get the results how you asked for them use UNPIVOT!

```
SELECT SUM(Sales) Sales,
       Name 
FROM Sales
UNPIVOT
    (Sales FOR Name IN ([Pencil Sales],[Notebook Sales],[Pen Sales])) SalesSummary
GROUP BY Name
```

Results:

```
Sales     Name
 15     Notebook Sales
 18     Pen Sales
 17     Pencil Sales
```